# How to hide a power automate button on a power bi report once clicked

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-automate

I have a power bi report that contains a power automate button, among other things the power automate button triggers a flow that posts a http request.

[image]

As you can see from the screen shot I also have a Measure called 'Status Value' this is basically some validation on the report, e.g. if the user has selected the correct amount of slicers then it is set to 1...

```
Status Value = IF([Form Ready] == TRUE(), 1, 0)
```

Form Ready is just a measure that counts if slicers are selected.

The flow attached to the power automate button does validation however I would like it so the button is disabled/hidden or won't trigger if 'Status Value' is set to 0.

I cant find anything that does such a thing, any ideas?